# how create a report for user activity in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

i have a content type, say named material, with fields and all, and users can create, modify and delete all nodes of content type material.

The task i need to do, is have a report on the activity of each user, in a per month, or a per year basis. Example user 1, has created the following nodes, in January, updated these nodes and how many times each node was updated by the particular user.

Is there a module, or a view that could help me do something like this?
Or should i go to MySQL and run a query there?

And how then this query should look like?

(I am still on version 7 of drupal)

for example the following will return will select all nodes created within the past hour (3600 seconds).

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE created > :created", array(
  ':created' => REQUEST_TIME - 3600,
));
```

But what i need is also all updates done by a certain user, for a certain period of time given...
Any example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: i suggest you this contrib module : https://www.drupal.org/project/user_activity_log

Comment: take a look to this feed https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112140/how-to-log-the-history-of-nodes-viewed-by-a-user-and-report-about-them

Comment: AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127777/track-users-action

Comment: the above module i think does not allow me to filter per month. Is there a possible view that could help me do the same?